# Page breaks for images in Python fpdf

Tags: python, fpdf

I want to insert some lengthy images (each image can extend to 2 pages) using python fpdf. But the images don't continue to next page once a page break is triggered. How can I print the rest of the images into the next page starting from a given set_y value (header included)?

Comment: you can resize image as page size. So image will be in single page. You cannot eliminate page break.

Comment: Image quality matters. Currently I'm trying to split the images and insert but there are lot of bugs and effecting performance. Anyways answer with a code example can help.

Answer (score 3):

Although I believe there is a way with `fpdf`, I suggest you switch to [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit) / wkhtmltopdf based solution.

I have many similar issues with `reportlab`, which is very like `fpdf`, then switched to wkhtmltopdf, feels much better.

With wkhtmltopdf, you could control layout with standard web stack, use CSS and javascript, use a favorite template engine, then convert HTML file to pdf, easier and much more powerful.

Comment: can't switch because I've done the entire template in fpdf (almost 300 lines).

Comment: we have migrated a ~2500 lines reportlab based project to wkhtmltopdf, but code lines count does not equal to maintenance difficulty, HTML/CSS is much much easier to debug with.

Answer (score 0):

If your pdf-dataset is a data string you can start searching for the "`\r`" and/or (multiple) '`\n`' character(s) using the below code:

```
chrs = ['\r', '\n', '\n\n']

for item in chars:
     pdf-data.replace(item)
```

In case its formatted strings in a list:

```
list = pdaf-data

for list-item in list:
    for list-item in chars:
         pdf-data.replace(item)
```

In case you read directly from a file use "open file, etc" and `readline()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just an example of my above comment,

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

im = Image.open('1.jpg')
width_img, height_img = im.size

#mm = (pixels * 25.4) / dpi
# - 25.4 millimeters in an inch
w = (width_img*25.4)/300
h = (height_img*25.4)/300

pdf.image('1.jpg',0,0,w,h)
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

Comment: How is this handling page breaks at all?

Comment: The above code does not handle  page break. Its just an example of my previous comment.

Comment: Then *put that in your answe*. And surely you can partition images to place them on multiple pages.

Comment: As far as I know we can't page break a pdf.

Comment: Of course you can; a PDF is all about pages. You may have to manually split images, but that’s just coding.